# Exchange 2010 Public Folder - Folder contact permission

Tags: exchange

What does the folder contact permission do? All I can seem to find is this description:

```
The user is the contact for the specified public folder.
```

Thanks,
Garrett

Answer (score 1):

The folder contact is a mailbox that will receive a messages about admin stuff for that folder.  Owners have this by default.  One example of a message is conflicts.  When conflicts occur like two people editing the same thing at the same time.  The folder contact will get a message asking which copy to keep.

I don't have a good reference but you will see it mentioned a lot in [this search.](http://www.google.com/search?q=public%20folder%20permissions%20conflict%20%22folder%20contact%22)

Answer (score 1):

A **Folder contact** Grants folder contact status to the specified user/email. Folder contacts receive automated notifications from the folder. I personally have never needed to use the feature but I believe that it is useful in large organisation where you would delegate staff to look after folders.

You could always set it to be your account/email address and see what happens. If you prefer you could create a test set up using something like virtualbox/vmware and play around without fear of breaking anything on a live system.

[Exchange permissions](http://danthedataman.wordpress.com/tag/outlook-2007/)